# Einstein manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Does an Einstein manifold have to have integer $\lambda$ constant?

Why a Riemannian product between two Einstein manifoldd with different $\lambda$ constant is not Einstein?

A manifold with constant sectional curvature is Einstein, while a manifold with constant scalar curvature may not be Einstein, why?

Comment: Your third question even suggests the answer to the first one, if you pay attention. For any $\lambda$, there are surfaces with constant Gaussian curvature $\lambda$ (flat plane, rescaled spheres and hyperbolic planes).

Comment: Thank you very much! So, all Einstein manifolds with negative $\lambda$ constant, are all isometric to a hyperbolic manifold, therefore all isometric to each other?

Comment: No. The examples I gave realizing all real numbers as Einstein constants were *surfaces*.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $\lambda$ can be any real number. It does not have to be an integer.
- If $M=M_1\times M_2$ with $Ric_i=\lambda_ig_i$ then $Ric(X_1,X_1)=\lambda_1 g_1(X_1,X_1)$ and $Ric(X_2,X_2)=\lambda_2 g_2(X_2,X_2)$. Thus if $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$ then $M$ is not Einstein.
- Having constant sectional curvature is more restrictive than having constant Ricci curvature. And having constant Ricci curvature is more restrictive than having constant scalar curvature. Thus: constant sectional curvature implies constant Ricci curvature (that is, Einstein) implies constant scalar curvature. But the converse converse implications are not true.

Comment: Thank you very much! Then a manifold with constant scalar could have Ricci curvature not constant

Comment: Yes. For very simple examples just have a look at this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127829/when-constant-scalar-curvature-implies-einstein

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Small clarification: the converse implications are not true in high enough dimensions. But constant Ricci curvature implies constant sectional curvature in dimensions 2 and 3, and constant scalar curvature implies constant Ricci and sectional curvatures in dimension 2.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification